# How to find out if a user has ever answered or commented on a question of mine?

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers

Is there a way to check if a particular user has ever answered or commented on one of my questions or commented on an answer to one of my questions? Also, is there a way to learn the opposite - if I ever answered/commented on one of their questions? Of course, needless to say I would like to be able to see which this question was (similar to how I see for which question I earned a badge).

Comment: better would be if you ever had an interaction with the user. But interaction itself is a relative and vague term here

Comment: Use google for example: "http://drupal.stackexchange.com bala , clive"

Comment: @hus787 - at first I wanted to formulate the question exactly using the word interaction, but I think this also includes an up/down vote, so I decided to be more precise.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you go using [Data.SE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/query/145339/posts-comments-by-askerid-and-answererid?AnswererUserId=187824&AskerUserId=186599):

```sql
--Answers on your question
SELECT 'Answers' AS Post_Type, p1.ID AS [Post Link], p1.* 
  FROM Posts p1
  JOIN Posts p2 ON p1.ID = p2.ParentId
   AND p2.OwnerUserId = ##AnswererUserId##
 WHERE p1.OwnerUserId = ##AskerUserId##
--Comments on your posts
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Comments on question' AS Post_Type, p1.ID AS [Post Link], p1.* 
  FROM Posts p1
  JOIN Comments c1 ON p1.ID = c1.PostID
   AND c1.UserId = ##AnswererUserId##
 WHERE p1.OwnerUserId = ##AskerUserId##
--Comments on answers of your question
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Comments on other answers' AS Post_Type, p2.ID AS [Post Link], p2.* 
  FROM Posts p1
  JOIN Posts p2 ON p1.ID = p2.ParentId
  JOIN Comments c1 ON p2.ID = c1.PostID
   AND c1.UserId = ##AnswererUserId##
 WHERE p1.OwnerUserId = ##AskerUserId##
   AND p1.ID <> p2.ID
```

Add other user's UserId as `AnswererUserId` and your UserId as `AskerUserId`. You can also do a viceversa. Here you can know whether it is an answer, a comment, or a comment on other's answres by the first column in the result (i.e. `Post_Type`)

Comment: I couldn't bring this query to work. Try this - my id (asker id) is 1836143, the id of user sawa is 314166. When I run the query with these parameters nothing happens. And sawa has [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19318897/1836143) at least one question of mine.

Comment: @AlexBG - Probably you have entered values for **Meta** Stack Overflow. Just switch the site. [See this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/145339/posts-comments-by-askerid-and-answererid?AnswererUserId=314166&AskerUserId=1836143)

Comment: @AlexBG - Also remember the Data.SE is updated weekly (early every Monday morning around 3:00 UTC). For more about Data.SE see it's [help section](http://data.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: One more interesting application of this query - if you enter yours (or somebody else's) id both as asker and answerer you'll get a list of all questions you have answered yourself.

Comment: @AlexBG - Yeah, also comments on your posts.